# If you will have vs If you have

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses

> If you **will have** dinner at home, tell me.
>
> or
>
> If you **have** dinner at home, tell me.

What is the difference between the two sentences? Which one sounds natural?

Answer (score 3):

> If you will have dinner at home, tell me.

Here "will" is used with the (slightly archaic) meaning of "wish/intend to", so the sentence is correct, but modern English speakers would generally use "wish/want/intend to" instead, or "would like to".

> If you have dinner at home, tell me.

This is a simple sentence that requests you to tell the speaker if you actually have dinner at home, so it is also grammatically correct but conveys a totally different meaning.

Comment: And "have dinner" can be ambiguous in some contexts, where it could mean "have food for dinner"...

Answer (score -3):

I think the second one is correct.

> If you have dinner at home, tell.

Although this [Source](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/will_would_if_clauses.htm) states:

> *When the situation or action depicted in the if-clause is a result of the main clause, the will-future is used in the if-clause.*
>
> He'll pay me $10 if I'll help him do the dishes. (Doing the dishes is the result of paying ten dollars.)

So in any other case, you would not have *will/would* in an *if* clause.

In your case, telling him is not the result of having dinner at home, but of planning to have dinner at home.

I hope this explains it correctly.

Comment: Could please someone share with me why my answer is downvoted?